# How to print ULONG_MAX without printf

Tags: c, limits

I am recoding the printf function. The problem is with limits, I cannot print ULONG_MAX number for instance.

```
printf("%lu", ULONG_MAX) gives me ->18446744073709551615

ft_putnbr(ULONG_MAX) gives me -> -1
```

I included the two following libraries :

```
<limits.h> 
<locale.h>
```

And put in my main():

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
```

My putnbr is a basic recursive function like this (works well with other numbers):

```
void    ft_putnbr(int nb)
{
    if (nb < 0)
    {
        ft_putchar('-');
        nb = -nb;
    }
    if (nb >= 10)
    {
        ft_putnbr(nb / 10);
        ft_putnbr(nb % 10);
    }
    else
    {
        ft_putchar(nb + '0');
    }
}
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Show the definition of `ft_myprintf()` as well

Comment: Add it to your question. And add ft_nb_arg, ft_print_it, and whatever else you are calling. Do you think people can read your mind?

Comment: Here is my code available: https://bitbucket.org/zikmout/ft_printf

Comment: Your `ft_putnbr()`  function takes an `int` parameter. How can that hold ULONG_MAX?

Comment: Ok I change it and try right now but I don't think it is going to make it work out...

Comment: what does it mean by "Does not work"? what does it output?

Comment: First off, you need to declare the argument to `ft_putnbr` as `unsigned long`.  Declaring it as `int` is doubly wrong:  (1) wrong size (2) signed instead of unsigned.  Once you've fixed that, look at the very first thing you do:  You see if it's less than `0`.  An unsigned can never be less than 0, so when properly declared, that test will always fail.  It's dead code.  Try making some fixes and posting the corrected code.

Comment: and how does an unsigned type have negative value?

Comment: I want to make it print the right number but now with it does now print the correct number with negative number

Answer (score 1):

Well the first thing you do is check to see if `nb` is less than `0`.

This is true in the case of `ULONG_MAX` (`nb` is passed as an `int`, not an `unsigned int`) so you take the first branch.

`"-"` is printed and then `-1` is turned to `1`.

The in the final iteration only the character `1` is printed.

Comment: Thank you it works !! I had to pass an unsigned long long int in order to get the maximum !!

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems that you have a bug hidden somewhere in code that is too long to show, I suggest that you go back to good old debugging.

Hint: A parameter of type int won't be able to hold every value of type unsigned long.

Comment: I edited the topic, I only try do show this number with my put_nbr thats all

Answer (score 0):

The bug is that your `ft_putnbr()` function takes an `int` parameter. There're two problems with that when you pass it a variable of type `unsigned long` as in this case. Both can be replicated with this snippet:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned long my_long = ULONG_MAX;
    int my_int = (int) my_long;
    printf("%lu\n", my_long);
    printf("%i\n", my_int);
}
```

The first problem is that the parameter is of a type of shorter length than the value you try to pass to the function. Let's assume that `long` is 2 bytes on our system while `int` is 1 byte (more realistically they would be 4 or 8 bytes). In binary, `ULONG_MAX` would then be `1111 1111 1111 1111`. However, when assigning that to `int`, which only is 1 byte, the value will be `1111 1111` as there's only room for 8 bits. In order to pass `ULONG_MAX`, we need a type of the same (or greater) length so there's room for all bits. For example, we could use `long` so that the function signature becomes `ft_putnbr(long nb);`.

There's, however, still one problem. The type `long` is signed (i.e., one of the bits is dedicated to keep track of whether the number is negative or positive) while `ULONG_MAX` is of unsigned type (i.e., only positive). In particular, if the first bit is 1, then that indicates that the number is negative. So a signed 2 byte type with binary value `1111 1111 1111 1111` will be negative. The reason that it becomes (decimal) `-1` is beyond this answer (but you can read about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

So, how can we solve both of these problems? One approach would be to let `ft_putnbr()` take a very wide signed type (e.g., `long long`) and never pass it any unsigned type of equal or greater length. Another approach would be to write two `ft_putnbr()` (with different names): one that takes the widest signed type and one that takes the widest unsigned type.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks to you guys I made it work for both limits (LONG_MAX & LONG_MIN):

```
void    ft_putnbr(long long int nb)
{
    if (nb == LONG_MIN)
        ft_putstr("-9223372036854775808");
    if (nb < 0 && nb != LONG_MIN)
    {
        ft_putchar('-');
        nb = -nb;
    }
    if (nb >= 10 && nb != LONG_MIN)
    {
        ft_putnbr(nb / 10);
        ft_putnbr(nb % 10);
    }
    else if (nb != LONG_MIN)
    {
        ft_putchar(nb + '0');
    }
}
```